# Using money-rails gem, switching instance currency to Euro breaks updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, money-rails

I have a model named `Widget` that has a single monetized attribute named `advance`.

Each instance of a `Widget` may have an `advance` attribute that stores a unique currency and amount.

Despite setting up everything based on the gem documentation, and having the ability to switch between the default currency `USD` and switching to other currencies, such as `JPY`, `CSD`, `CNY`, switching to `EUR` throws errors and prevents updating the `advance_currency` and `advance_cents` values.

### Gem File

```rb
ruby "3.1.2"
gem "rails", "7.0.2.3"
gem "money-rails", "1.15.0"
```

### Initializer File

```rb
Money.locale_backend = :currency

MoneyRails.configure do |config|
  config.default_currency = :usd
  config.include_validations = true
  config.rounding_mode = BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_UP
end
```

### Migration Setup

```rb
create_table :widgets, force: :cascade do |t|

  ...

  t.monetize :advance, amount: { limit: 8 }
end
```

### Schema

```rb
create_table "widgets", force: :cascade do |t|

    ...

    t.bigint "advance_cents", default: 0, null: false
    t.string "advance_currency", default: "USD", null: false

    ...

end
```

### Model Setup

```rb
class Widget < ApplicationRecord

  ...

  monetize :advance_cents, with_model_currency: :advance_currency

  ...

end
```

### Edit Form View Snippet

```html
  <div class="form-floating">
    <%= select_tag("advance_currency", options_for_select(CurrencyTypes.options_for_select, @instance.advance_currency), prompt: "Select a currency", class: "form-select") %>
    <label for="advance_currency" class="form-label">Advance Currency</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" id="advance" name="advance" value="<%= number_to_currency(@instance.advance, unit: "", separator: ".") %>">
    <label for="advance" class="form-label">Advance Amount</label>
  </div>
```

### Controller Update Action

```rb
def update
  instance = controller_class.find(params[:id])
  instance.update(update_params)

  ...

end

private

def update_params
  params.permit(

    ...

    :advance,
    :advance_currency,

    ...

  )
end
```

### Messages Switching to Yen (Works)

#### Params Check

```rb
#<ActionController::Parameters {

  ...

  "advance_currency"=>"JPY",
  "advance"=>"987.65", 
} permitted: false>
```

#### Debugging Update

```rb
> instance.update(update_params)
> instance.save

true
```

#### Debugging Errors

```rb
> instance.errors

#<ActiveModel::Errors []>
```

### Error Message(s) Switching to Euro (Doesn't Work)

#### Params Check

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {

  ...

  "advance_currency"=>"EUR",
  "advance"=>"123.45", 
} permitted: false>
```

#### Debugging Update

```
> instance.update(update_params)
> instance.save

false
```

#### Debugging Errors

```
> instance.errors

#<ActiveModel::Errors [#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=advance, type=invalid_currency, options={:thousands=>".", :decimal=>",", :currency=>"123.45", :attribute=>"Advance"}>]>
```

What doesn't make any sense is that when switching to Euro as the currency, the advance amount seems to be entered into the `currency` value instead of `EUR`.

I have no idea why one currency throws off the money-rails gem operations while the others work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the use of the `number` type input is the problem.

You can only submit values in Euro with the `123.456,78` format instead of `123,456.78` for the other currencies.

Since a comma is not allowed in the `number` input type, you must switch to a type of `text`

### Not Working

```html
<div class="form-floating">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="advance" name="advance" value="<%= @instance.advance %>">
  <label for="advance" class="form-label">Advance Amount</label>
</div>
```

### Working

```html
<div class="form-floating">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="advance" name="advance" value="<%= @instance.advance %>">
  <label for="advance" class="form-label">Advance Amount</label>
</div>
```